# i'm getting an error type Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type String? when i use the result of _determinPsition to fill the form field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on some project in flutter and I have some problem I'm unable to solve. I'm looking for someone who can help me

I want to get the user's location and use the information to fill the `TextFormField`. when I try to print the result, everything's fine with the output in the console. but I can't use the result in my build method when I want to set the initial value of my form field

```
//the function to get user location

    _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high) ;
    print(position);
    setState(() {
      _locationMessage = "${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}, ${position.altitude}";
    });
    return _locationMessage;
    //return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high) ;

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
      child: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildNom(),
            _buildDate(),
// i'm trying to use the response of the fonction _determinePosition to fill the 
// Textformfield


        TextFormField(

          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'adresse', icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
          initialValue:  _determinePosition(), // here is my problem
          enabled: false,

        ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.redAccent)),
              onPressed: _valid,
              child: Text(
                'Valider',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

now my problem is about the package geocoding when i try to get the adresse i have two kind of error:

when i use the virtual device:

```
PlatformException(NOT_FOUND, No address information found for supplied coordinates (latitude: 37.421998, longitude: 5.000000)., null, null)
```

when i use a physical device:

```
I/dalvikvm(22991): Could not find method android.location.Location.hasSpeedAccuracy, referenced from method com.baseflow.geolocator.location.LocationMapper.toHashMap
W/dalvikvm(22991): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1486: Landroid/location/Location;.hasSpeedAccuracy ()Z
D/dalvikvm(22991): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0085
```

i try to search the solution but i don't find it.

Comment: What is the actual error shown when you set the initial value, which you claim you cannot do?

Comment: when i set the initial value, i can't set the value in the TextFormfield, it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand what is Future. You can't simply return values from Future functions. In order to obtain value from these kind of functions, you need to await them because they work asynchronously.

In your code, define a String value and assing 'Something' to it. Then when you init initialvalue, setState the geolocation data to the String value you pre defined.

Another solution that may helps you to get location data inside initialValue.

```
// new line
String value = '';


   Future<String> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high) ;
    print(position);
    setState(() {
      _locationMessage = "${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}, ${position.altitude}";
    });
// new line

setState((){
value = _locationMessage;
})

    //return _locationMessage;
    //return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high) ;

  }

// call _determinePosition inside initState

@override
void initState(){
_determinePosition();
super.initState();
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
      child: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildNom(),
            _buildDate(),
// i'm trying to use the response of the fonction _determinePosition to fill the 
// Textformfield


        TextFormField(

          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'adresse', icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
          initialValue:  value, // here is my problem
          enabled: false,

        ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.redAccent)),
              onPressed: _valid,
              child: Text(
                'Valider',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! i just try with the code that you send me! now i don't have the error but the Field of adress is empty, it's not initialized with the value. can you please try to explain me why ? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you debug it? print your _locationmessage to see if the service returns your data.

Comment: i solved the problem by using FutureBuilder. thanks you for your help